# <p:selectOneRadio> is not working within <p:rowExpansion>

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am facing problem of using `<p:selectOneRadio>` within `<p:rowExpansion>`.

In my application I have a `<p:dataTable>`, in `<p:rowExpansion>` I have another 
`<p:datatable>` whose row contains a `<p:selectOneRadio>`. Now this `<p:selectOneRadio>` doesn't alwayes show properly. But instead of `<p:selectOneRadio>`
if I use `<h:outputText>` remaining the value attribute same as the `<p:selectOneRadio>` then value displays properly.

.xhtml code snippet given below:

```
<p:dataTable id="activityTable" value="#{activityDataModel}"
    var="activity" lazy="true" paginator="true"
    paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="10" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,25,50,75"
    styleClass="activityTable" widgetVar="activityDataTable" >
    <p:column id="rowToggle" styleClass="rowtoggle">
        <p:rowToggler />
    </p:column>
    <!--   All columns   -->
    <p:rowExpansion>
            <p:row>
                <p:column>
                    <p:dataTable id="userDataList" value="#{activity.activityUsersWithActivityManagers}"
                        var="user" styleClass="hide-column-names" type="ordered" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
                            <p:column>
                                <h:outputText value="#{rowIndex + 1}. #{user.firstName}/>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:selectOneRadio id="roleRadio" value="#{user.activitySpecificRole}">
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="User" itemLabel="User" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Manager" itemLabel="Manager" />
                                </p:selectOneRadio>
                            </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
    </p:rowExpansion>
</p:dataTable>
```

If I use
     `<p:column>

                  <h:outputText value="#{user.activitySpecificRole}" />

      </p:column>`

instead of `<p:selectOneRadio>` then it displays correct text.
I am using PF-3.4+ Mojarra(2.0).
Can anyone tell me where I am doing wrong?? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by the value is not displayed properly?

Comment: @user1983983 : If I use `#{user.activitySpecificRole}` in `<h:outputText>` then value displays always properly. But in case of `<p:selectOneRadio>` corresponding radio button is not selected for the vale of `#{user.activitySpecificRole}`. Suppose value of `#{user.activitySpecificRole}` is `Manager` so radio button with `Manager` value should be selected. But here that radio button is not selected always.